# How can I display the test name *after* the test using pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

Most of the time when I'm using pytest, the output is very, very long. More than a hundred lines. And often times I want this output, I really do. `--tb=short` isn't *really* a very good approach. But I don't want to have to scroll back 200 lines in my tmux window to find my test output because that's *also* super annoying.

What I would love to have is something like this:

```
______________________ >>test_my_test_with_a_lot_of_output _______________________
# imagine lots of test output here
______________________ <<test_my_test_with_a_lot_of_output _______________________
```

Is there some flag or setting I can use in py.test to achieve this kind of output?

Answer (score 13):

Use "pytest -rA" when running tests

see docs [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#command-line-flags)

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Using pytest 6.2.4 I don't see "-A" in the interactive help. Has it been renamed?

Comment: @IainSamuelMcLeanElder you can find it under `-r chars` (the space can optionally be dropped, which is how it becomes `-rA`) where `A` stands for "All".

Comment: This can be useful for certain important requirements, such as seeing the order in which tests are executed. But the problem for me is that it doesn't "interleave" the mention of the test name with the output to stdout and stderr (i.e. when also using the -s switch)

Answer (score 8):

You can add one fixture in your main/root `conftest.py` which would be called automatically before and after every test-case. Like

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
def test_log(request):
    logging.info("Test '{}' STARTED".format(request.node.nodeid)) # Here logging is used, you can use whatever you want to use for logs
    def fin():
        logging.info("Test '{}' COMPLETED".format(request.node.nodeid))
    request.addfinalizer(fin)
```

Here, `request.node.nodeid` gives you a name of your test.

Comment: Nice approach. One minor problem though is that `STARTED` will be printed within test setup clause and `COMPLETED` in test teardown clause: `[captured stdout setup] Test abc STARTED; [captured stdout call] Long output here... [captured stdout teardown] Test abc COMPLETED` But still this approach is much more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a simple way to achieve this using hooks. But here is how I would implement this.
It is not an ideal implementation though.

```
# contest.py
import pytest
import _pytest

class TerminalReporter(_pytest.terminal.TerminalReporter):
    def _gettestname(self, rep):
        # actually "rename" original method for clarity
        return super()._getfailureheadline(rep)

    def _getfailureheadline(self, rep):
        # instead of test name
        # (which is originally printed at the top of report)
        # return prefixed name
        return '>>' + self._gettestname(rep)

    def _outrep_summary(self, rep):
        super()._outrep_summary(rep)
        # after printing test report end, print out test name again
        # XXX: here we hard-code color, so red will be used even for passed tests
        # (if passes logging is enabled)
        # You can add some more logic with analyzing report status
        self.write_sep('_', '<<' + self._gettestname(rep), red=True)

@pytest.hookimpl(trylast=True)
def pytest_configure(config):
    # overwrite original TerminalReporter plugin with our subclass
    # we want this hook to be executed after all other implementations
    # to be able to unregister original plugin
    reporter = TerminalReporter(config)
    config.pluginmanager.unregister(name='terminalreporter')
    config.pluginmanager.register(reporter, 'terminalreporter')
```

For inspiration about extending this approach head to `_pytest.terminal.TerinalReporter` class sources.